# Opening Paradox database; 'PDOXUSRS.NET' workaround?

Tags: delphi, data-migration, delphi-xe3, bde, paradox

I'm writing an application that has to open a preexisting BDE database that has been saved by a third party.

In this application, I currently have a `TDatabase` (`DriverName`: `STANDARD`) with `path` set correctly in `Params`.
I can now set `Connected` to true without an error message.

There is also a `TTable` with `DatabaseName` set to the values of the TDatabase and `TableName` set to the .db-file that lies in the folder (the name was automatically filled in, I only hat to select it).

Now the problem:
If I set `Active` to true, an error message complains about missing access rights for `C:\PDOXUSRS.NET`.
I know I could set another path using `BDEADMIN`, but I need to solve this in my application - I can't expect every customer to do this change.
Furthermore, I have a test machine with the third party application running - it can access the database without any error, while my application throws the aforementioned error. This leads me to the suspicion there might be a workaround.

Is there such a workaround?
I only need read access to the database.

Comment: you might try to change it programmatically http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23231

Comment: If all else fails, you could try to skip the BDE and access the Paradox tables through a dbExpress ODBC driver, like this one:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dbexpress/

Comment: Are you running Windows 7? You probably can't access the root of C:. Try changing the directory of the net file to a directory under your user name. You should be able to do this with a program called BDEAdmin.

Comment: The best option is to change database access layer from BDE to built-in Microsoft ODBC driver for Paradox tables. BDE requires separate drivers delivery and installation. You likely get more questions from customers about this process than about changing `pdoxusrs.net` directory path.

Comment: How to connect to Paradox db on the flight with ODBC and specify custom network directory: http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=90#ODBCDriverForParadox or http://docs.30c.org/conn/paradox.html#microsoft-paradox-driver-odbc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it thanks to the [link of bummi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23231)
Thank you very much.

Quote:

> **How to change NET DIR programmatically so it persists**
>   *[...]*
>   You should also remember that if you have programs that change their own NET DIR locations at runtime, using either the DbiSetProp function or the NetFileDir property of a TSession component, this will override the NET DIR value in the configuration file.

It pointed me to the possibility of changing the NET DIR in code:

```
Session.NetFileDir := MyCustomTempDir;
```

After doing that, `Table1.active := true` works and the data shows up in a connected `TDBGrid`.