# I am trying to open a paradox database (*.db file) with a paradox view and I get the message ("Network initialization falied.Permision denied.

Tags: delphi, paradox

I am trying to open a paradox database (*.db file) with a paradox viewer and I get the following message (Network initialization failed.Permission denied.File C:\PDOXUSRS.NET. Windows7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Paradox database; 'PDOXUSRS.NET' workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915807/opening-paradox-database-pdoxusrs-net-workaround)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while so you may have to check some details.
The PDOXUSERS.net file is a lock file for the Paradox tables. When a table is opened it will place your ID in the file and table/row details.
It appears to be located in the root directory which is a bad option. Your app probably does not have write permissions there.
If the app is networked it should be in a shared location. If it is not networked it should be in a writeable folder.
The location is set in the BDE config application.
I do not have access to a BDE so cannot help any further.

Answer (score 0):

In addition try to run Delphi in Administrator mode